# Kafka ItemWriter for Spring Batch for Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've created a Spring Batch application which reads data from file and write to database. I want to write output data into Kafka. I've tried to use Spring Cloud Data Flow but could not even run it.

I've followed that tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

when I register it to Spring Cloud Data Flow it gives a status as N/A. I've checked that tutorial: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-data-flow-batch-processing and added `@EnableTask` to my application class but result is same.

My question is: I want to write data to Kafka and use that Spring Batch job at Spring Cloud Data Flow. How can I do that?

Comment: What environment are you running Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) in?  Local, Kubernetes, CloudFoundry, etc?

Comment: I use local mode.

Comment: What data do you want to write to Kafka?  Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) just launches the über jar...it doesn't do anything from a processing standpoint so if running your app via `java -jar foo.jar` doesn't work, adding SCDF won't change that.

Comment: Running my jar works. The reason is I want to pipeline my applications.

Comment: So what doesn't work?  What is the exception?  Etc?

Comment: @kamaci Did you find a clean solution for this problem. There is pretty limited expertise on this particular topic. I will post once I found the solution